# Change the starting View in a tabbed iOS application

Tags: ios, view, startup, appdelegate

i have created a tabbed application and created another file, called LogInScreen, 
I want to change the usual view which comes up at the application launch to this new LogInFile, but everything I tried didn't work.

This is the AppDelegate.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LogInScreen.h"

@interface LogInScreen : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) LogInScreen *logInView;

@end


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

At the first @implementation appears an error message: Duplicate interface definition for class 'LogInScreen', I guess because of the LogInScreen.h file. I don't know how to get it to work properly.

And this the start of the AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  [self.logInView addSubview:_logInView.view];
  [self.logInView makeKeyAndVisible];
  [self.logInView setRootViewController:_logInView];


// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

I found this code on this website, but it didn't work...

Here's the LogInScreen.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LogInScreen : UIViewController{

  NSString *password;

  IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;

}

- (IBAction)enterPassword;

- (IBAction)savepassword:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)returnKey:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)switchView:(id)sender;


@end
```

and the LogInScreen.m:

```
#import "LogInScreen.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
/* #import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain()(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
 */

@interface LogInScreen ()

@end

@implementation LogInScreen

- (IBAction)enterPassword
{
NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12345"];

if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
    /*[self switchView:nil]; */
}

else {
    UIAlertView *incorrectPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Falsches   Passwort" message:@"Dieses Passwort ist falsch! Geben Sie bitte das korrekte Passwort ein!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Zurück" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [incorrectPassword show];
}
}

- (IBAction)savepassword:(id)sender {
password = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:passwordField.text];
[passwordField setText:password];
NSUserDefaults *stringDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[stringDefault setObject:password forKey:@"stringKey"];
}

- (IBAction)returnKey:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)switchView:(id)sender {
FirstViewController *main = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:main animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[passwordField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey"]];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Would be cool if someone could help me

Comment: The IDE is called Xcode, not xCode, but anyway, it isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: Do you want have a login screen before access to tabbed main view?

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, you can use this code to show a modal login view before your main tabbed view:

```
// Main menu view controller    
MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainNavigationController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window.rootViewController.view setOpaque:NO];
self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Login modal view controller
LoginViewController *loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:loginController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, or I put this code in the wrong file... but I tried a few and it didn't work... :(

Comment: Put it under - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Place your login screen as intial view in MainStoryBoard .Drag a drop a uitabbarcontroller connect a segue from loginscreen to uitabbar and present modal that tabbar from a button in the login screen .